# Adding buttons to admin user list section of moodle

Tags: plugins, moodle

I need to add a button for each user in admin's user list (`admin/user.php`).
is it possible to do it from my local plugin? if yes how?

Or I need to edit the user modules manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this without a core code modification, would be to use the theme (or possibly a local plugin) to inject some javascript into the page to add the button after the page has loaded.

The page itself is quite old, so it doesn't use a renderer, so overriding the generated HTML via the theme is not an option. The user actions aren't designed to be pluginable either.

Depending on what you are wanting to do, you could, of course, create a local plugin that adds a new link to the 'Site administration' tree. On the page this links to, you could add your own list of users, with whatever buttons you wanted on them.